# Sub Categories Keep Redirecting to Pages With Same Slugs

Tags: categories, permalinks, redirect

What I want to do is have a `news` category with two sub categories (`property-registration` and `property-revitalization`). Going to /news works fine. However going to */news/property-registration* or */news/property-revitalization* redirects to same-named pages instead (`/programs/property-registration` and `/programs/property-revitalization` instead). I have downloaded a couple of plugins that let me save templates to categories but none of them worked and still got the same results. My permalink structure is `/%category%/%postname%/` for reference and no category base is set.

Comment: What  is the question? As you have found out your permalink structures can not handle pages and posts with the same slug so either use a different one  or use different slugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. By adding `/.` at the end of the category base fixed the problem. So it is `news/.` instead of `news`.